# Domain user cannot be found

Tags: 2007, active-directory, people-picker

I'm trying to add my domain account as a secondary site collection admin but for some reason it can't find the account.

I'm currently logged in with servcenter\my.name but the people picker does not seem to find the account. the server hosting sharepoint is most definitely on the domain.

I've tried to look at the people picker configuration but can't find anything weird about it.

Comment: did u search for your name in the people finder (address book icon)? Did you search for any other accounts in the same domain like you? Is it only with your account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your username instead: ie. for Jim Bob (mydomain\jim.bob) who has a username jbob try mydomain\jbob.

Confirm you the web application has the authentication provider set to Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether the Application pool is running under a domain account? The reason why it could fail in your scenario is, the people picker is executing under the application pool account which is a local account and cannot be recognized by AD, then it will not be able to query other accounts in AD.

Two options are available for this case.

-> Use domain accounts for application pool

-> Configure people picker searchadforests

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460%28office.12%29.aspx

Comment: deepu, i ran tha searchadforests command as stated but this didn't help. also the application pool is running under servdept\adaccount, but i need servcenter\my.account which the searchadforests command should have fixed?

Comment: Just to know- Why dont you try running the application pool under a user in the servcenter domain? Do u need help on that?